# Can I change pricing of inapp purchase after app submission

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

Can I change the pricing of inapp purchase after submitting app to the appstore.
And I want to know whether we can use custom prices like $1.75 or $2.50 etc

If these are not possible how can I implement these functionalities

Comment: Have you tried textView.string = @"$2.50"? Oh no sorry, my solution will not work I thought it is programming question ;)

Comment: TweetWithThisOwl_FollowMe is right in saying this is not a programming question - there are more and more app-store related questions here. Please consider joining [Area 51 - App Stores](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores)

Answer (score 3):

a) Yes, you can change the pricing of app or in-app purchase at any stage.

b) No, you can only use predefined price tiers. There's an unofficial document here: App [Store Pricing Matrix](http://www.app-machine.com/hmcms_media/public/files/ApplePreis_Matrix.pdf)

As for *implementing this functionalities*: everything related to managing your application in the App Store is done trough [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa). Where you can also get official price matrix but you'll need a developer account and a signed contract with Apple first.

Comment: In case you are looking for the official price matrix: App Store Connect > Your app > Features > In-App Purchases > (select one) > All Prices and Currencies > Download All Prices and Currencies